# Getting the trusted X509Certificate for a Java SSLSocket

Tags: java, ssl

I'm able to establish a TLS connection to https://google.com/. The remote service returns a chain of 3 certificates:

- `CN=www.google.com, O=Google Inc, L=Mountain View, ST=California, C=US`
- `CN=Google Internet Authority G2, O=Google Inc, C=US`
- `CN=GeoTrust Global CA, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US`

These certificates can be retrieved like so:

```
Certificate[] certificates = sslSocket.getSession().getPeerCertificates();
```

Unfortunately, this isn’t the complete chain. There’s a 4th certificate that’s installed in my local SSL context’s TrustManager. It looks like this:

- `OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority, O=Equifax, C=US`

Retrieving its name is straightforward:

```
String equifax = ((X509Certificate) peerCertificates[2]).getIssuerDN().getName();
```

What I want instead is the `X509Certificate` instance. **How do I get the trusted CA cert that was used during a `SSLSocket` handshake?**

Note that I’m using the system’s `TrustManager` by creating the SSL context like this:

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(null, null, null);
```

Comment: You'll have to search your truststore for a CertEntry with that IssuerDN as its SubjectDN.

Comment: @EJP any idea what APIs I can use to conduct such a search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there, just use the JVM default trust manager:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
    SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket("www.google.com", 443);

    X509Certificate[] chain = socket.getSession().getPeerCertificateChain();

    String equifax = chain[2].getIssuerDN().getName();

    // JVM Default Trust Managers
    TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    trustManagerFactory.init((KeyStore) null);
    TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();

    X509TrustManager manager = (X509TrustManager) trustManagers[0];

    for (java.security.cert.X509Certificate x509Certificate : manager.getAcceptedIssuers()) {
        if (equifax.equals(x509Certificate.getSubjectDN().getName())) {
            System.out.println(x509Certificate);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @frant.hartm. I would love to find a way to lookup the `X509TrustManager` from the `SSLSocketFactory` or `SSLSocket` since my API doesn’t _require_ the default. But this answers the question as posed!

Comment: (The API I’m exposing to my users is a `SSLSocketFactory`. Most users will use the default, but some won’t. Sigh.)
http://square.github.io/okhttp/javadoc/com/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient.html#setSslSocketFactory-javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory-

Answer (score 0):

For perpetuity, I ended up getting the data I wanted with [dirty reflection](https://github.com/square/okhttp/pull/2285/files). I’m unable to control how the caller builds the SSL Context, as advised above.